# Is it possible to hide the instancer and only show instanced objects in render?

Tags: instances

I have a question for you. I need to duplicate an object along a curve without deformation. Therefore I instance a plane along the curve. I made the cube a child of the plane and checked "Face" on the plane instancing setting. If I render the scene there is still the plane and I can't just hide the parent object and not the child. Do you know if their is a solution to hide the plane and not the cube?

Ps : I don't want to apply the instance because I want to animate the curve to move all the elements along it.

Thank's for all !

[image: hideproblem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the plane, switch to the object tab (as already shown in your screenshot) and disable *Render Instancer*. This will hide the plane object in your render. If you also want to hide it in the viewport, you can disable *Display Instancer*.

[image: Instancing options]

Comment: Oh thank's ! sorry, that was so simple haha

Comment: @CorentinMontant if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.